# Ubuntu 16.04: After minimizing a window, it cannot be maximized again

Tags: 16.04, compiz, window-manager

Windowas randomly disappear after I minimize them and do not reappear after I click on them. Doing alt+tab shows me the minimized window, but even then, it won't maximize after clicking on it.

Comment: The only reason that I can think of is that the minimized windows are moving to a desktop which you don't have access to. Are you using the desktop cube?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and [the comment on the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929914/ubuntu-16-04-after-minimizing-a-window-it-cannot-be-maximized-again/1105958#comment1471620_929914) nailed the answer.

I enabled the other workspaces (desktops) by going to **Settings > Appearance > Behavior > Enable Workspaces**.  All the lost windows came back immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. I selected the window using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and then look for the window in the upper left corner. I found out the window is just so small that you can't see it. Just find it and resize it.

Ps: Looking for it is the fun way. For a more straightforward solution just select the window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to maximise the current window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had moved my quick launcher by mistake.

To fix it, right click on a empty part of your panel bar, select **Panel Properties**, and uncheck *Expand*. You should see them now. All you have to do now is move the quick launcher back to the left and recheck *Expand*.